# Cyrillic and latin characters in same document

Tags: table-of-contents, cyrillic

I am working in a document in Ukrainian with some acronyms and short texts in english/latin characters. In the preamble I have:

```
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{paratype}
\usepackage[OT2, T1, T2A]{fontenc}
```

I have set chapter, index ... names in Ukrainian.
With this setup when a title has an acronym in latin characters it is written in the body of the document as it should, with cyrillic and latin characters, but in the ToC latin characters are written with their cyrillic equivalents.
If I change the order of languages (`\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}`) the problem is solved but hyphenation in Ukrainian is lost. Is there any way to get the latin characters right in the ToC using the `[english, ukrainian]` option?

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, article,twoside, openright, table]{memoir} 
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{paratype}
\usepackage[OT2, T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[automake,nonumberlist,acronym,nomain,nopostdot=true,
style=super,
stylemods=longragged,
nogroupskip
 ]{glossaries-extra}
 \usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linktocpage, linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\makeglossaries
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym,abbreviation]{short}
\makeglossaries
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym,abbreviation]{short}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\clearpage
\chapter{Конституція - FSTD}
Конституція – це основний закон держави, сукупність правових норм, які відрізняються від звичайних законів тим, що формулюють і затверджують найзагальніші, основоположні принципи державного життя, утворення, оновлення і здійснення державної влади, закріплюють головні засади суспільного й державного устрою країни, існуючу в ній політичну систему, форму правління, правовий стан особи, принципи й порядок утворення та діяльності органів влади й управління, їх компетенцію, організацію та головні засади правосуддя, виборчої системи тощо.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please show a short example of code?

Comment: Tks, I am not very familiar with this site, I have modified my question including (I guess that this is not the way) an excerpt of my code

Comment: Try without `OT2`.

Comment: The code lacks examples of acronyms.

Comment: @egreg FSTD, which gets converted to ФСТД in the toc.

Comment: I'm not sure why OT2 takes over when the TOC is compiled. In any case, you should remove the OT2 option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the OT2 encoding takes over when typesetting the table of contents.

Anyway, you don't need this font encoding. Just do

```
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
```

If you *really* need the OT2 encoding, then load `fontenc` before `babel`, which is a good thing to do anyway.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, article,twoside, openright, table]{memoir} 
\usepackage[OT2, T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{paratype}

\usepackage[
  automake,nonumberlist,acronym,nomain,nopostdot=true,
  style=super,
  stylemods=longragged,
  nogroupskip
]{glossaries-extra}
%\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linktocpage, linkcolor=black]{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym,abbreviation]{short}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*
\clearpage

\chapter{Конституція - FSTD}

Конституція – це основний закон держави, сукупність правових норм, які 
відрізняються від звичайних законів тим, що формулюють і затверджують 
найзагальніші, основоположні принципи державного життя, утворення, 
оновлення і здійснення державної влади, закріплюють головні засади 
суспільного й державного устрою країни, існуючу в ній політичну систему, 
форму правління, правовий стан особи, принципи й порядок утворення та 
діяльності органів влади й управління, їх компетенцію, організацію та 
головні засади правосуддя, виборчої системи тощо.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You don't need to load `tocloft`. Actually, this is an emulated package in `memoir`, so loading it or not doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Thank you, I found another solution using \foreignlanguage in the titles of chapters and sections: \chapter{Конституція - \foreignlanguage{english}{FSTD}}